# texas holdem full house showing in table, splitting pot among players

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

Texas holdem, KKK22 full house showing on table.

Player 2 has the K2 hole cards to make the same full house, is the pot split among all players or is it player 2 pot?

Answer (score 1):

If player 2 has K2 in the hole and the community cards are KKK22, then player 2 has KKKK2 as their best hand, 4 of a kind, which beats everyone else's community full house.

That being said, if everyone had their hand made up of the community cards, or perhaps someone had a 2, matching the pair (which has to be lower than the three of the kind), the hand is a push and all players still in the game at that point get an equal share of the pot, or whatever of the pots they are still in (If short stacked players go all in, that can create side pots between those that had more chips left and still bet). Only 5 cards per player matter in holdem, and in most poker variants in general, whether they come from the hole, the river, the turn or the flop doesn't have any bearing on who wins and loses.